# JS Variable inside another variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that would use other variables, depending on what has been passed.

Like `this = ActionBar(slot)` slot contains "one".

and I would like to create a call inside that like `object.slot.name` but it should convert it before hand to make the command look like `object.one.name`. Is there a way to do this in javascript/jquery?

I remember vaguely that some other language does this as {slot} or something like that.

Sorry if this question was already asked, I've checked google and stackoverflow too, but didn't find an answer.

Also I'd like to know what's the proper programming term for this kind of variable passing?

Edited it cause of misunderstandings. I'm looking into OOP js, so object is an object, one is an object, and name is an attribute, but when passing I'm passing "one" as a string to the function.

Tried eval, it doesn't work while dotted with an object.

Source code:

```
function disableActionButton(slot){
    $("#"+slot).attr("disabled","disabled")
    gcd = player.slot.gcd*1000
    cd = setInterval(function(){
            gcd = gcd - 10
            $("#"+slot).val(gcd+"ms").css("color","red");
    },10)
    setTimeout(function(){
            window.clearInterval(cd)
            $("#"+slot).removeAttr("disabled").css("color","black").val(player.slot.name);
    }, player.slot.gcd*1000)    
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `slot={};slot.name="one"`or shorter `var slot = {"name":"one"}`

Comment: First you have a string, then you have an object? Not sure how this is suppose to work, but you can use the namespace, and if it's global it would be `window[slot].name` etc.

Comment: Your edit doesn't really clear anything up. Code is worth a thousand words, show *actual* definitions for the things you're talking about.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder added source code.

Comment: Why doesn't `object[slot].name` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>It's really unclear what your current structure is</s> *(much clearer now you've posted code, see "update" below)*, but fundamentally the way to do this *sort* of thing in JavaScript is to have a container object. (If you don't already have one, introduce one.) Then `slot` can refer to a property of that object, like this:

```
var container = {
    one: "This is one",
    two: "This is two"
};

// ...

function foo(slot) {
    console.log(container[slot]);
}

// ...

foo("one"); // ends up logging "This is one"
foo("two"); // ends up logging "This is two"
```

This works because the container object has properties, which in JavaScript can be referred to in two different ways:

1. Using dot notation and a literal name, e.g. `container.one`, or
2. Using bracketed notation and a name in a string, e.g. `container["one"]`.

They're exactly equivalent except where the property name comes from. And of course, in the second case, the property name needn't be a *literal* string, it can be the result of any expression, including a variable reference (e.g., you can get the name from `slot`).

This works with all object properties, including properties that refer to functions. I mention this only because you mentioned functions in your question, so if you need to, you can do this:

```
function foo(slot) {
    container[slot]();
}
```

...which calls the function on `container` that the property with the name held by the `slot` argument. So if `slot` is `"one"`, it does `container.one()`.

---

**Update**:

Your source directly echos the container example above, just apply the above to it:

```
function disableActionButton(slot){
    $("#"+slot).attr("disabled","disabled")
    // ---------v----v---- here
    gcd = player[slot].gcd*1000
    cd = setInterval(function(){
            gcd = gcd - 10
            $("#"+slot).val(gcd+"ms").css("color","red");
    },10)
    setTimeout(function(){
            window.clearInterval(cd)
    // ------------------------------------------------------------ and here--v----v
            $("#"+slot).removeAttr("disabled").css("color","black").val(player[slot].name);
    // ------v----v------- and here
    }, player[slot].gcd*1000)    
}
```

Or, rather than looking up the slot data each time, grab it once and reuse it:

```
function disableActionButton(slot){
    // Grab it once...
    var slotdata = player[slot];

    $("#"+slot).attr("disabled","disabled")
    // ---vvvvvvvvv--- then use it
    gcd = slotdata.gcd*1000
    cd = setInterval(function(){
            gcd = gcd - 10
            $("#"+slot).val(gcd+"ms").css("color","red");
    },10)
    setTimeout(function(){
            window.clearInterval(cd)
            $("#"+slot).removeAttr("disabled").css("color","black").val(slotdata.name);
    }, slotdata.gcd*1000)    
}
```

There's no special name for this. You're passing a property name into a function, and the function is looking up the property on the `player` object using that name. In some other languages this might be called "reflection" but the term doesn't really apply to dynamic languages like JavaScript.

Comment: @Tusk: Good deal, glad that helped.